# Trying to create a shell script to move all files with a certain year in their name to a year based directory

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script, find

Here is the block of code that I have so far. No matter what I do with the find command, I can't seem to get it to function as I want. Trying to move all files with these long year names into their own named directories.

```
for i in 2008 2009 2010 2011
do
mkdir /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/$i
find /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/ -iname '*$i*' -maxdepth 1  -type f  -exec mv -n {} /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/$i/ \;
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
find /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/ -iname '*$i*' -maxdepth 1  -type f  -exec mv -n {} /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/$i/ \;
```

With:

```
find /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$i*" -type f  -exec mv -n {} /Users/benjaminbaker/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/$i/ \;
```

The problem was that `$i` does not expand within single-quotes.  So, use `"*$i*"` in place of `'*$i*'`.

Also, `find` prefers that you specify options, like `-maxdepth`, before tests, like `-iname`.  In the code above, the order was changed accordingly.

Lastly, in two places you use `...Test/$i` without quotes.  This works here only because `$i` contains no whitespace.  If it did, it should be in double-quotes.

Comment: Made it a little better, but still not executing correctly. The second $i is being replaced with nothing, so it tried to move the files back to the same directory of origin

Comment: @GentilmanMyles It works fine for me. If it is not working for you, you will need to be more specific about what you are actually doing. For example, if `$i` has a value, the shell will never replace it with "nothing".

Comment: Or sometimes I'm just being idiotic and screwing up my for loop when adding this in. Thanks. Fixed and works.

Comment: @GentilmanMyles Very good.  Glad it works.